# Does the hard Lefschetz theorem hold for hyperplane sections for singular subvarieties of smooth projective varieties?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $Y$ is a hypersurface of a smooth projective $X$. For which degree k values defined below, do we always get isomorphism when studying the cohomology of $Y$? What can be said about the general version of this? If $Y$ is a subvariety of codimension say $i$, to which codimension $i$ and to which $k$ do we get isomorphism between $H^{n - k}(X) \cong H^{n + k}(X)$?

Comment: Do you mean the Lefschetz hyperplane theorem, which covers a hyperplane section of a variety, and not the hard Lefschetz theorem, which involves only the cohomology of a single variety?

Comment: If everything takes place in $Y$, how is $X$ relevant? Ever singular projective variety is a subvariety of a smooth projective variety (e.g. $\mathbb P^n$ for $n$ sufficiently large.)

Comment: @WillSawin Just because the $Y$ comes from hyperplane section on $X$ so there is more control over the singularities.

Comment: @WillSawin We know that  is smooth and − is smooth is it possible to deduce $H^{n - k}(Y) \cong H^{n + k}(Y)$?

Comment: No, this is not sufficient. The cone on a smooth projective hypersurface of lower dimension is a good example - it is itself a singular projective hypersurface, but has complicated cohomology in the "wrong" degree and thus doesn't satisfy hard Lefschetz. But please edit your question to include all the relevant information (for example that $Y$ is a hypersurface in $X$)

Comment: I think one can probably prove the map $H^{n-k} \to H^{n+k}$ is an isomorphism for $k$ greater than the dimension of the singular locus of $X$ plus one.